# Optimize queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SuiviRupture]
    (@CodeArticle [NVARCHAR](13),
     @CodeSite [NVARCHAR](5), 
     @CodeStructure [NVARCHAR](13))
RETURNS @calcul TABLE (CAMOY FLOAT, QTEMOY FLOAT)
AS 
BEGIN
    WITH temp AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.[datecol], t1.[Prix de vente TTC],
            t1.Quantité 
        FROM 
            [V_VentePromo] t1
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT 
                 [datecol], [Code Article], [Code Structure],
                 [Code Site], 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Code Article], [Code Structure], [Code Site] 
                                   ORDER BY [datecol] DESC) AS rn
             FROM 
                 (SELECT DISTINCT  
                      [datecol], [Code Article], [Code Structure], [Code Site]
                  FROM 
                      [V_VentePromo] t2
                  WHERE 
                      [Code Article] = @CodeArticle 
                      AND [Code Site] = @CodeSite 
                      AND [Code Structure] = @CodeStructure) g
          ) a ON a.datecol = t1.datecol
                 AND t1.[Code Article] = a.[Code Article]
                 AND t1.[Code Structure] = a.[Code Structure]
                 AND t1.[Code Site] = a.[Code Site]
        WHERE 
            t1.[Code Article] = @CodeArticle 
            AND t1.[Code Site] = @CodeSite 
            AND t1.[Code Structure] = @CodeStructure
            AND rn <= 28
    )
    INSERT @calcul 
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct [datecol]) = 0 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE SUM(convert(float, Quantité)) / count(distinct [datecol]) 
            END as QTEMOY,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct [datecol]) = 0 
                    THEN 0 
                    ELSE SUM(convert(float, [Prix de vente TTC])) / count(distinct [datecol]) 
            END AS CAMOY
        FROM 
            temp
     RETURN;
END;
```

I call this function by this query

```
SELECT  
    t1.[Code Article], t1.[Code Site], t1.[Code Structure], 
    u.QTEMOY, u.CAMOY
FROM 
    V_distinctVente t1
CROSS APPLY 
    dbo.[SuiviRupture](t1.[Code Article], t1.[Code Site], t1.[Code Structure]) u
```

[image]

The execution time is too long, I have a number of rows of V_distinctVente  about 10 000 000. How to optimize it?How could Icombine main query with the T-SQL code of the TVF in one query?it's executed row by row in the main query

Comment: You didn't post very much in the way of details here. Do you realize that your function columns are reversed? You define the table as CAMOY, QTEMOY but your insert is the other way around. I am a bit concerned about your table valued function. It has the same view in there twice. What does that view look like? And you have an outer view also, what does it look like? Do you have nested views going on? How about posting the actual execution plan instead of a partial screenshot?

Comment: @SeanLange How could post all the execution plan ?

Comment: To post an execution plan you first save it, then attach it to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can very easily be transformed into an *inline TVF*. The *old fashioned TVF with BEGIN...END* needs a table's declaration and is known for very bad performance.

Other the inline TVF (or *ad-hoc* TVF): This is fully inlined and behaves like a VIEW. Try it like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SuiviRupture](@CodeArticle [NVARCHAR](13),@CodeSite [NVARCHAR](5) ,@CodeStructure [NVARCHAR](13))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
WITH temp AS (
 SELECT t1.[datecol],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.Quantité 
      FROM [V_VentePromo] t1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  [Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site] ORDER BY [datecol]desc ) AS rn

      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  [datecol],[Code Article],[Code Structure],[Code Site]
           FROM [V_VentePromo] t2
            WHERE [Code Article]= @CodeArticle AND [Code Site]=@CodeSite AND [Code Structure]=@CodeStructure
    )g
          ) a
           ON a.datecol=t1.datecol
            AND t1.[Code Article] = a.[Code Article]
            AND t1.[Code Structure]=a.[Code Structure]
            AND t1.[Code Site]=a.[Code Site]
            WHERE   t1.[Code Article]= @CodeArticle AND t1.[Code Site]=@CodeSite AND t1.[Code Structure]=@CodeStructure
            AND  rn <= 28

)
SELECT 

    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT [datecol])  =0 THEN 0 ELSE   SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,Quantité))/COUNT(DISTINCT [datecol]) END  AS QTEMOY
    ,  CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT [datecol])  =0 THEN 0 ELSE  SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,[Prix de vente TTC])) / COUNT(DISTINCT [datecol])END AS CAMOY
FROM temp
;
GO
```

Comment: I try it . It almost the same time execution .

Comment: could I transform the function into stored procedure?or it would be worst?

Comment: No, ad-hoc SQL will be faster. Try to take out parts and find where the most time is lost...

Comment: How could Icombine main query with the T-SQL code of the TVF in one query?it's executed row by row in the main query